# Shortcut for switching Google Chrome tabs on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: google-chrome, osx-mountain-lion

In Google Chrome on my work computer, if I press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc., it switches to the corresponding tab.

On my home machine, I can’t figure out how to do the same. I’ve tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc. without success.

I might have set this up manually a while ago but have since forgotten how.

Can anybody explain how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your home machine is OSX, correct? 
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> to go to the neighboring tabs. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd>/<kbd>4</kbd>/etc works fine for me (I'm on OSX ML as well).

Comment: Home machine is incorrect which is driving me crazy, i'm a developer and very shortcut orientated. I should of put this in my original post, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: cmd alt left/rigtht works, I wonder why the cmd tab number doesnt!

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go forward and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go backward.

Comment: Not talking about open applications, talking about tabs within chrome.

Comment: I meant the same. :) I do it and it works in my chrome. I think this feature remains same regardless of your OS (Mac, Linux, Windows etc...)